# SwiftUI + Core Data - updating an object (Detail -> DetailEdit)

Tags: core-data, swiftui, xcode11

Goal: update a core data object with SwiftUI:  DetailView -> EditDetail -> DetailView (updated).

Problem: code bellow works, but creates a new object, instead of updating existing one.

```
import SwiftUI

struct DetailView: View {
    
    var order = Order()
    
    @State var showOrderEdit = false


    var body: some View {
        
        Form{
        
        Text(order.tableNumber)
        Text(order.pizzaType)
            
        }
        .navigationTitle(order.pizzaType)
        
        .toolbar {

            ToolbarItem(placement: .primaryAction) {
                
                
                //edit button
                Button(action: {
                    showOrderEdit = true
                }, label: {
                    Text("Edit")
                })
                .sheet(isPresented: $showOrderEdit) {
                    OrderEdit(order: order)
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

```
import SwiftUI

struct DetailEdit: View {
    
    @State var tableNumber = ""
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @Environment (\.presentationMode) var presentationMode

    var order = Order()

    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {

        
        Form {
        
            TextField("table number", text: $tableNumber)
            
            
            //update button
            Button(action: {
                updateOrder(order: order)
            }) {
                Text("Update")
                    .foregroundColor(.blue)
            }
        
        }
        
        //passing data item detail -> item edit
        .onAppear {
            self.tableNumber = self.order.tableNumber
        }
        
        .navigationTitle("Edit Order")

    }
}
    
    func updateOrder(order: Order) {
        let newtableNumber = tableNumber
        viewContext.performAndWait {
            order.tableNumber = newtableNumber
            try? viewContext.save()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create new `Order` object in each view, so it is stored as new one into database. Instead you need to inject CoreData object from parent view (which shows DetailView) as observed object,

```
struct DetailView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var order: Order   // << here !!
    
// .. other code
```

and

```
struct DetailEdit: View {
    
    @State var tableNumber = ""
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @Environment (\.presentationMode) var presentationMode

    @ObservedObject var order: Order          // << here !!

// ... other code
```

in such approach you will work with same instance of `Order` in both views and they will be updated because observe that instance for modifications.

Comment: genius, mate! do you have patron so I can send you a small donation?